# File descriptors before fork()

Tags: c, unix, fork, file-descriptor

I know that if I call the `open` function before the `fork()`, the IO pointer is shared between the processes.

If one of these processes closes the file calling the `close(fd)` function, will the other processes still be capable to write/read the file or will the file be closed for everyone?

Comment: Yes - The file descriptors and there functionality is copied

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Each process has a copy of the file descriptor (among other things). So one process closing it won't affect the copy of the `fd` in other process.

From [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) manual:

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
>             descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same
>             open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file
>             descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two descriptors
>             share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-
>             driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and
>             F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

From [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) manual:

> If fd is the last file descriptor referring to the underlying open
>          file description (see open(2)), the resources associated with the
>          open file description are freed; if the descriptor was the last
>          reference to a file which has been removed using unlink(2), the file
>          is deleted.

So if you do `close(fd);` it closes only the reference in that process and other process holding another reference to the same file descriptor can continue to operate on it.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a child process is created, it gets a copy of the file descriptor table from the parent process. And there is a reference count corresponding to each file descriptor, that is the number of processes currently accessing the file. So, if a file is open in master process and a child process is created, the reference count increments, as it is now open in child process as well, and when it is closed in any of the processes, it decrements. A file is finally closed when the reference count reaches zero.